# Firewall stop working and serveral other problems after recent windows7 update

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, firewall

After the last windows7 update Suddenly the firewall stopped working.
I did a system restore (before the update) and it worked fine again.
The problem what occurs are:
1) Firewall shutdown (error code 0x8007042x)
   according to serveral forums it has something to do with the almost obligated windows 10 update
2) Lost Aero-effects
3) Some programmas don't start from task scheduler.

It seems to have something to do with the windows10 update, but I'm still on windows7 and i can't find any solution for this error.

Answer (score 0):

After having this problem for days and tried all the solution what were in forums given, nothing helped. 
I found this issue had a deeper problem. Like a service what didn’t start   “Base filtering Engine (BFE)
Serveral solutions reported here How to Repair Base Filtering Engine Service Startup Problems?

However this solution didn’t work for me.  The reported error was ‘Error 5: Access deinied” But I got BFE: Error 6

Then on the avast forum someone suggested that the matrix (you need it when you have  raid configuration) driver caused the issue.

I don’t have a raid configuration but Matrix was there anyway, so I updated all the drivers

detailed list how I got my problem fixed is [here](https://richard2009.wordpress.com/2016/06/04/simple-solutions-for-computer-issues/)